# How do you reword this sentence into a shorter one

Tags: idiomatic-language

> They need to develop the country into a secular and prosperous country
>   **for other countries to adopt as a model.**

I am not sure why, but the sentence sounds weird and ungrammatical. Is it grammatical? Is it idiomatic? Is this what we call a dangling phrase? I am unsure if this can be considered as an error in an essay. Is it bad style? If so, why?

Comment: What do you mean? The sentence is understandable. The only thing that might be distracting is the repetition.

Comment: ...easily resolved by *a secular and prosperous country for **others** to adopt as a model* (and perhaps remove the syntactically unnecessary direct object ***the country*** in the initial clause).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's "writing advice"